# Nginx Proxy Stops After 38 kB

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, node.js, proxypass

I have a simple nginx 1.4.6 proxy running on a dedicated Ubuntu 14 server. My configuration looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:44400;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

When I try to reach [this file](https://example.com) it times out after sending a small part of it. It always stops at the same line.

The backend is running a Node.js/Koa server, the file can be loaded directly without any issues.

When loading via nginx Koa reports a broken pipe error when trying to write, since the problem only occurs with nginx I don't think it's Koa's fault.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly check nginx logs. It helps you (and us) to understand error.

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Possible problem is bad permissions (user owner) for nginx tmp folder

```
cd /var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/ && ls -la
```

Check nginx config for field "user xxxx" (for example user apache;")

```
grep "user " /etc/nginx/*
```

Found user must be owner of nginx tmp dir. So, for example, if your nginx user is apache, and owner of nginx tmp dirs is anoter -- change it to apache.

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/lib/nginx/*
```

Also check memory / disk state:

```
htop

df -h
```

I hope, it'll help you.

And what about sending static content directly from nginx?

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
    root your/content/root/path;
    error_page 404 = @fallback;
}
```

Comment: Also make sense smart cleanup tmp/proxy/ if problem is in permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will try this later today.

Regarding your static content suggestion: I will be using the impequid subdomain to 1) host the files needed for the client & 2) for some HTTP/WS APIs, these won't have a file extension, so I'm unsure how to apply that RegExp to them.

Comment: The permission fix doesn't stick. It keeps getting changed from `http` to `www-data`. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Not sure if you get this without a mention, so here you go @zhecky.

Comment: @Dodekeract you got the same error message in log again?

Comment: I'd assume that, because the folders changed their owners back to www-data.

Comment: Yes, same error again @zhecky.

Comment: @Dodekeract hmm, maybe try `chown` recursively? `chown -R apache:apache /var/lib/nginx/*`

Comment: I did already do that, the changes seem to get reset, it worked fine for some time then stopped working